# JVM -XX:MaxRAMPercentage not being applied in container

Tags: java, docker, containers, amazon-ecs

I am trying to run a Java app which requires a large heap. It is running on AWS ECS inside a container. On a host with 128GB RAM. The container has ~115GB assigned.

The Dockerfile is based on `eclipse-temurin:11`

I am launching with the option `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=85.0` and also `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` to get feedback. This is what I get abridged (too large for SO) Full flags here https://pastebin.com/jm7Md2c8

```
2023-01-17 11:02:40      bool MaxFDLimit                               = true                                      {product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40     uintx MaxGCMinorPauseMillis                    = 18446744073709551615                      {product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40     uintx MaxGCPauseMillis                         = 200                                       {product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40     uintx MaxHeapFreeRatio                         = 70                                     {manageable} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40    size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 32178700288                               {product} {ergonomic}
2023-01-17 11:02:40      intx MaxInlineLevel                           = 15                                        {product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40      intx MaxInlineSize                            = 35                                        {product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40    size_t MaxMetaspaceExpansion                    = 5451776                                   {product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40     uintx MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio                    = 70                                        {product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40    size_t MaxMetaspaceSize                         = 18446744073709547520                      {product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40    size_t MaxNewSize                               = 19306381312                               {product} {ergonomic}
2023-01-17 11:02:40      intx MaxNodeLimit                             = 80000                                  {C2 product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40  uint64_t MaxRAM                                   = 137438953472                           {pd product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40     uintx MaxRAMFraction                           = 4                                         {product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40    double MaxRAMPercentage                         = 85.000000                                 {product} {command line}
2023-01-17 11:02:40      intx MaxRecursiveInlineLevel                  = 1                                         {product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40     uintx MaxTenuringThreshold                     = 15                                        {product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40      intx MaxTrivialSize                           = 6                                         {product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40      intx MaxVectorSize                            = 32                                     {C2 product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40    size_t MetaspaceSize                            = 21807104                               {pd product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40      bool MethodFlushing                           = true                                      {product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40    size_t MinHeapDeltaBytes                        = 4194304                                   {product} {ergonomic}
2023-01-17 11:02:40     uintx MinHeapFreeRatio                         = 40                                     {manageable} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40      intx MinInliningThreshold                     = 250                                       {product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40      intx MinJumpTableSize                         = 10                                  {C2 pd product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40    size_t MinMetaspaceExpansion                    = 339968                                    {product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40     uintx MinMetaspaceFreeRatio                    = 40                                        {product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40     uintx MinRAMFraction                           = 2                                         {product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40    double MinRAMPercentage                         = 50.000000                                 {product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40     uintx MinSurvivorRatio                         = 3                                         {product} {default}
2023-01-17 11:02:40      bool UseContainerSupport                      = true                                      {product} {default}
```

So it seems reasonable, the JVM detected the host ram `MaxRAM = 137438953472` = 128GB the option `MaxRAMPercentage = 85.000000` was correctly set. `UseContainerSupport = true` so my understanding is these options should be applied.

So I dont understand why `MaxHeapSize = 32178700288` which is only ~29.9GB? I think its 1/4 of the 115GB assigned to the container which seems to imply my settings are not being applied, why?.

Testing locally with

```
docker run --memory='2g' eclipse-temurin:11 java -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=85.0 -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep MaxHeapSize
```

Appears to work as expected when varying the container memory assigned and the `MaxRAMPercentage`

Comment: 'The container has ~115GB assigned.' - what's your container definition?

Comment: add `-XX:-UseCompressedOops`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/TU37JBnW I have removed a few identifying bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3426309/andrey-b-panfilov). The solution was to add `-XX:-UseCompressedOops`

Comment: pls note, that workaround is required for java versions `<=11`: [JDK-8213175 : Java ergonomics limits heap to 32GB to allow compressed oops](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8213175)